# correr un código varias veces sin perder los datos ingresados anteriormente en .Net c#

Tags: c#, .net, consola, array

Amigos, necesito ayuda con esta parte de un ejercicio,el ejercicio es el típico donde ingresas n datos y los muestras en pantalla y luego te pregunta si "quieres volver a ingresar datos". no sé como puedo almacenar nuevos datos al correr el código nuevamente sin perder los datos ingresados anteriormente...
"Luego de mostrar, deberá preguntar si desea ingresar otro paciente, en caso de ser positiva la respuesta, deberá poder hacer todo el proceso nuevamente (sin perder los datos anteriores). En caso de no querer ingresar otro paciente, mostrará un resumen del día:
Total de pacientes atendidos
Total recaudado en el día
Total de perros
Total de gatos"
de ante manos muchas gracias, saludos!.

Comment: Necesitas una base de datos, si utilizas C# puedes usar Microsoft SQL Server

Comment: _no se usan objetos ni interface_ ¿Entonces como programas en C#?

Comment: @NaCl, obviamente el OP esta iniciando su aprendizaje en C# y en programacion en general, al decir Interface me imagino que se refiere a la interfaz grafica, y al decir que no se usan objetos quiere decir que no esta utilizando el paradigma completo de Programacion Orientados Objetos en toda su plenitud.

Comment: Bueno, ¿El op tiene algo intentado que nos pueda mostrar?

Comment: hola amigos, edite la pregunta porque no quedaba muy clara, no estoy usando bases de datos ni interfaz, solo uso aplicaciones de Consola de windows C#, es decir, solo corro el código y lo muestro en cmd..

Comment: @JordanBlakeTold ¿Has intentado algo? Código con el que podríamos ayudarte a resolver tu duda.

Comment: ya te entendí Jordan, te sugiero que almacenes los datos en algún archivo ya sea de texto, xml o json, te recomiendo este último, aquí tienes información relevante a ello: http://javierescobar.net/introduccion-a-json/ y http://javierescobar.net/como-implementar-json-con-csharp/ saludos :D

Comment: Realmente para lo que solicita Jordan no se necesitan ni bases de datos, ni utilizar una definición de objetos, ni una interfaz grafica (Windows). El solamente requiere una aplicación de consola que le permita almacenar un arreglo con la información solicitada y sostenerlo en memoria mientras el programa está en ejecución. Pero Jordan!!! si quieres una colaboración adecuada, pon algo del código que estas haciendo, por que la política de stackoverflow no es hacerte las tareas, debes demostrar algo de esfuerzo en la búsqueda de la solución de tu problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
            string[] preguntas = {"animal","edad","sexo"};
            //la mayor ventaja del list es que puedes agregar tanto elementos como desees
            // en un array bidimensional tienes que declarar el tamaño maximo
            int max_len = 500;        
            string[,] respuestas = new string[max_len, preguntas.Length];


            int i=0;
            do {
             for(int j=0;j<preguntas.Length;j++){
                   Console.WriteLine(preguntas[j]);
                   respuestas[i,j]=Console.ReadLine();           
             }
             i++;
             Console.WriteLine("otro paciente y/n");
                if (Console.ReadLine() != "y") break;

            } 
            while (true);

            int perro=0;
            int gato=0;

            for (int n = 0; n < i; n++)
            {
                if (respuestas[n, 0] == "perro")
                {
                    perro++;
                }else if (respuestas[n, 0] == "gato"){
                    gato++;
                }
                for (int j = 0; j < preguntas.Length; j++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(preguntas[j]);
                    Console.WriteLine(respuestas[n, j]);
                }

            }
            Console.WriteLine("total");
            Console.WriteLine(i);
            Console.WriteLine("total perros");
            Console.WriteLine(perro);
            Console.WriteLine("total gatos");
            Console.WriteLine(gato);
            Console.ReadLine();
```

Considero que la respuesta de Carlos Muñoz es la mejor implementacion.
pero dado que el OP pidio solo usar arrays aqui hay otra implementacion que no utiliza list

Answer (score 1):

Hola bueno utiliza un array de string como interfaz, solo recuerda la posicion en la cual va cada dato y listo, tenes algo parecido al almacenamiento un objeto pero sin comportamiento, luego arma otro array de eso y podras almacernarlos, es engorroso pero si no usas objetos es una salida.

Si no te dejan usar array usa un string largo y caracteres especiales para separar los campos y otro diferente para separar las filas. cada ves que agregues una persona solo deverias concatenar un string con los parametros

para contar la cantidad solo deberas contar la cantidad de caracteres separadores de fila para saber la cantidad de personas que tienes.

Son implementaciones rebuscadas pero bueno. Ideal seria definir objetos personas y manejar un array con ellos pero bueno el problema especifica que no.

Saludos.

Comment: Hola amigo, si puedo usar array, el ejercicio se trata de aprender el uso de los array de uni y multi dimensional, además del manejo de los String, hasta el momento tengo el programa completo hecho hasta la parte donde muestra los datos, pero no sé como manejar arreglos de forma que se guarden nuevos datos después de un ciclo.

Comment: para agregar un valor al array `personas.Add(persona)`

Comment: Perdon era para los objetos List, para un array deberias definer una variable indice  y hacer `personas[indice] = persona` cada ves que agregues un elemento incrementar el indice en uno, de paso al final te servira para contar la cantidad de elementos.

Answer (score 1):

```
string[] preguntas = { "animal", "edad", "sexo" };
var respuestas = new List<string[]>();

do
{
    var fila = new string[preguntas.Length];
    for (var j = 0; j < preguntas.Length; j++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(preguntas[j]);
        fila[j] = Console.ReadLine();
    }   
    respuestas.Add(fila);

    Console.WriteLine("otro paciente y/n");
    if (Console.ReadLine() != "y") break;
}
while (true);
```

no es la mejor implementacion pero espero que te ayude

Comment: Tu código tiene errores de sintaxis

Comment: Lo edité para que haga lo que habías pensado

Comment: ok, a mi tambien me parece que un List es lo mas sencillo de utilizar, pero OP queria usar Arrays bidimensionales no List

Comment: muchas gracias amigos, ya me solvio la duda con lo acotado por carlos y jorge, saludos :D.